# Tikz dashed on smooth cycle leaves "gap"

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm having problems with drawing closed, smooth and dashed lines in Tikz using smooth cycle. The issue is that I get a small "gap" where the line is supposed to close. This only happens when the line is dashed (the dash pattern doesn't matter!), as illustrated below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [line width=3mm,dash pattern=on 30 pt off 10 pt] plot [smooth cycle,tension=0.65] coordinates
     {(-1,-0.577) (0,1.155) (1,-0.577)};    

    \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
        \draw [line width=3mm] plot [smooth cycle,tension=0.65] coordinates
        {(-1,-0.577) (0,1.155) (1,-0.577)}; 
    \end{scope}      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Gives the output:

[image]

The gap can be seen at the very top of the left figure, as a thin white line. (N.B. When I converted to PNG the gap became much smaller than what it was in the original PDF file, but it is still visible). Is it possible to remove this?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) where exactly is that gap, I see no gap in the image you posted or if I preview the pdf generated by the MWE

Comment: This is viewer dependent. I see a big gap when using Okular, but none when using Firefox's viewer or Evince. In my opinion, Firefox's viewer is the one which gets closer to the printed version is most documents. What viewer are you using?

Comment: If you want a robust solution then you need to add two more additional points very close to each other at the start and at the end such that the line angles match.

Comment: You can close the gap by hand by adding \fill (0,1.155) circle (1.5mm);  `.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I'm getting a big gap on TeXStudios built in viewer and a small one on PDF-XChange Editor. No gap in Acrobat Reader DC. I'll try to close it manually with a small circle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is about the viewer, it is not related to LaTeX or Ti*k*Z.